# Markov chains: Expected time until absorption.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose you have the following Markov Chain {$X_n$} $n=0,1,2,3$ with transition probability matrix:

$P=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0&0&0\\P_{10} &P_{11}&P_{12}&P_{13}\\P_{20}&P_{21} &P_{22}&P_{23}\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

So clearly 0 and 3 are absorption states while 1 and 2 are transient.

If I define

$T=min(n\ge0;X_n=0$ or $X_n=3$)

$P_{ij}=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)$ probability to go from i to j in one step.

$u_i=P(X_T=0|X_0=i)$ $u_i$ is the probability of absorption in state 0 starting from state i.

$v_i=E[T|X_0=i]$ $v_i$ is expected time until absorption.

Could someone explain/show the MATHEMATICAL developments starting from the formula $v_i=E[T|X_0=i]$ and ending up with the equations:

$v_1=1+P_{11}v_1+P_{12}v_2$

$v_2=1+P_{21}v_1+P_{22}v_2$

it would be fine to just show how to do $v_1$ or $v_2$, either one.

I am not super interested in whatever "intuitiv explanation" of how you get these equations for $v_1$ and $v_2$, I am more interested in the mathematical developments starting from just the formula for $v_i$ given above and showing all the steps and how they end up with said equations.

Obviously I understand that $v_0=v_3=0$ has to be since 0 and 3 are absorption states and that a process can never "leave" once its absorbed.

In a similar way I am also interested to understand how the equations for the u's make sense mathematically.

$u_1=P_{10}+P_{11}u_1+P_{12}u_2$

$u_2=P_{20}+P_{21}u_1+P_{22}u_2$

starting from just $u_i=P(X_T=0|X_0=i)$

Here as well I understand that the probability to get absorped in 0 if you start in 3 is 0 so $u_3=P(X_T=0|X_0=3)=0$ and that the probabitliy to get absorped in 0 starting from 0 is 1 so $u_0=P(X_T=0|X_0=0)=1$

So the equation for $u_1$

is given by $u_1=P_{10}u_0+P_{11}u_1+P_{12}u_2+P_{13}u_3$

or written in another form

$P(X_T=0|X_0=1)=P(X_1=1|X_0=0)P(X_T=0|X_0=0)+P(X_1=1|X_0=1)P(X_T=0|X_0=1)+P(X_1=1|X_0=2)P(X_T=0|X_0=2)+P(X_1=1|X_0=3)P(X_T=0|X_0=3)$

why exactly is the left hand side and right hand side equal? is this just the law of total probability or whatever it is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, for $i=1$ we have

$E[T|X_0=1]= E[T|X_0=1,X_1=1]P_{ 11}+ E[T|X_0=1,X_1=2]P_{ 12}+ E[T|X_0=1,X_1=3or0](P_{ 10}+P_{13}) $

Which by the Markov property is (and doing a plus minus one at the same time)

$E[T|X_0=1]= E[(T-1)+1|X_1=1]P_{ 11}+ E[(T-1)+1|X_1=2]P_{ 12}+ E[(T-1)+1|X_1=3or0]( P_{ 10}+P_{13})
= E[(T-1)|X_1=1]P_{ 11}+ E[(T-1)|X_1=2]P_{ 12}+ E[(T-1)|X_1=3or0]( P_{ 10}+P_{13})+( P_{ 11} +P_{ 12} +P_{ 10} +P_{ 13}),$

where the last bracket equals 1.

Then, since we have a time homogenous Markov chain,

$E[(T-1)|X_1=1] = E[T|X_0=1] $.

(Similarily for the other expectations).

The other equations for $u_i$ and $v_i$ follow similarily. Total probability law is the right intuition.

Comment: $E[(T-1)+1|X_1=1]P_{ 11}+ E[(T-1)+1|X_1=2]P_{ 12}+ E[(T-1)+1|X_1=3or0]( P_{ 10}+P_{13})
= E[(T-1)|X_1=1]P_{ 11}+ E[(T-1)|X_1=2]P_{ 12}+ E[(T-1)|X_1=3or0]( P_{ 10}+P_{13})+1$ I am not entirely understanding this step, how do you take the +1 out of the conditional expectation or whatever I should call it? Also I have never heard about the strong markov property before, is it just $E[(T-1)|X_1=1] = E[T|X_0=1]$ ? Additionally: Since $E[(T-1)|X_1=1] = E[T|X_0=1]$ I suppose $E[(T-1)|X_1=2] = E[T|X_0=2] $ etc?

Comment: @stat333 The +1 is measurable (known) with respect to the given information (it is just a constant) so it can be moved out of the expectation (indeed of every of the expectations so we get a +1 since all the probabilities sum to one). Strong Markov Property is probably used more in continuous time setting. Just forget about the "strong". Markov Property alone is ok for this case. And  yep, you suppose right.

Comment: ok I see, thanks a lot but one last thing: Isn't the markov property just that $P(X_{n+1}=j|X_0=i,...,X_{n-1},X_n=i)=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)$ how does $E[(T-1)|X_1=1] = E[T|X_0=1]$ follow from that? I am not really that used to working with expectations.

Comment: @stat333 It means also the memory less property. In continuous time they use a so called time shift operator which I didn't want to use here. So $T$ as you defined it, is a random variable on $1,2,..$ showing the number of steps since $X_0$. Given $X_1$, $T$ is on $2,3,....$ since it has already increased by one in the step $X_0\toX_1$. So I subtract 1 to get a random variable on $0,1,2,...$ again. By the Markov Property (meaning it doesn't matter how we reached $X_1$) it follows that the probability distribution of $T-1$ given $X_1=i$ is the same as the one of $T$ given $X_0=i$.

Comment: To be more precise, in my previous comment I should have written "it doesn't matter how or when we reached state $i$"

Comment: Sorry for the late edit, but I think it is more precise to mention time homogeneity to get the last equation.

Comment: $E[(T−1)+1|X_1=1]P_{11}$ can be written as $E[(T-1)|X_1=1]P_{11} + E[1|X_1=1]P_{11}$, directly from the formula E(a+b)=E(a) + E(b) right?